# Converting New Java code to an older Java syntax

Tags: java, servlets, thread-local

I'm trying to convert a class written in Java 1.8 to Java 1.4.  This is an older Java application but I've never coded in Java 1.4 before.

Here is the Java 1.8 code:

```
public class RequestContext implements Filter {

    private static final ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest> REQUEST_HOLDER = new ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest>();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            REQUEST_HOLDER.set((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
        }

        try {
            chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
        finally {
            REQUEST_HOLDER.remove(); // Clean up the ThreadLocal
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the HttpServletRequest for the current thread.
     */
    public static HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return REQUEST_HOLDER.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

How do I convert the above to Java 1.4?

Comment: I'd recommend downloading and reviewing the [Java 1.4 SDK documentation](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-142docs-2045554.html) and going line by line, based on compiler errors.

Comment: What is the version of Java EE and Servlet spec that you are targeting with Java 1.4?

Comment: Why would you want to? Who exactly told you that investing time to backport to a java version that had end of life 2008?

Comment: Why do you care?  This is an older application that runs on 1.4.

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody has explicitly mentioned setting the **-source** level for compilation to 1.4 (`javac -source 1.4 etc...`). Any use of features implemented after 1.4 will then be flagged by the compiler. Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have to target [Servlet 2.3 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/first/jsr053/servlet23_PFD.pdf) or newer as it introduced `Filter`. As per docs:

> Filters are a new feature in the Java servlet API for version 2.3.

It looks like that you have to remove generics as they were introduced in Java 1.5. `ThreadLocal` is available from Java 1.2, although [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#remove()) method was introduced in 1.5. The code should probably look like:

```
public class RequestContext implements Filter {

    private static final ThreadLocal REQUEST_HOLDER = new ThreadLocal();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            REQUEST_HOLDER.set(servletRequest);
        }
        try {
            chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        } finally {
            REQUEST_HOLDER.set(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the HttpServletRequest for the current thread.
     */
    public static HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return (HttpServletRequest) REQUEST_HOLDER.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```